# How can I preserve leading whitespace in this ZPL?

Tags: printing, whitespace, zebra-printers, zpl

I  am trying to print a receipt with a zebra QLn320 printer.
I am sending whitespace so that the ":" characters appear aligned in the ticket:

```
^XA^LL256^POI^FO20,20^ADN,10,8^CI10^FB550,9999,,L^FD
\&
           CRA : jab \&
   Contrato No : \&
     Domicilio : RAMBLA DEL POBLENOU \&
^FS^XZ
```

However, the printer is striping the leading whitespaces and the printed result is:

```
CRA : jab
Contrato No :
Domicilio : RAMBLA DEL POBLENOU
```

So, how can I add "indent" the without having to set a ^FO for each line?

Answer (score 0):

```
^XA^LL256^POI^FO20,20^ADN,10,8^CI10^FD

           CRA : jab 
   Contrato No : 
     Domicilio : RAMBLA DEL POBLENOU 
^FS^XZ
```

I don't have a printer available at present, so I haven't tested this.

I believe that it's the `^FB` that's causing your problem - especially the `L` option that's `L`eft-justifying your data.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason you do not want to separate this into multiple lines? When printing receipts I have found it useful to treat each line as a complete format.

```
^XA^LL30^POI^FO10,20^ADN,10,8^CI10^FD           CRA : jab^FS^XZ
^XA^LL30^POI^FO10,20^ADN,10,8^CI10^FD   Contrato No :^FS^XZ
^XA^LL30^POI^FO10,20^ADN,10,8^CI10^FD     Domicilio : RAMBLA DEL POBLENOU^FS^XZ
```

I too did not print this out so the LL and FO will likely need to be adjusted. You may also want to put the printer in rewind mode. ^MMR this stops the printer from moving the media after printing. Then you just print a blank line or two at the end of the receipt to get it where you want.

I like doing receipts this way so I do not need to compute the length of the receipt beforehand.